# Relation between the BACnet 4 layers and the TCP/IP 5 layers

Tags: ip, tcp, network

How are the BACnet 4 layers (physical, data link, network, application),
related to the TCP/IP 5 layers (physical, data link, network, transport, application)?

Are they separate of them, or build on top of them, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

BACnet and TCP/IP are two different protocol stacks. They’re roughly analogous to each other.

Comment: Yes I know but I am comparing because BACnet is usually used in an internet environment (TCP/IP).

Comment: @XY BACnet/IP is one possible form of BACnet - in that case it runs on top of UDP's transport layer.

Comment: @Zac67 so it runs on top of UDP's transport layer .. why not in top of IP's network layer, since it is BACnet/IP ?

Comment: You'd need to ask the vendors why they named it as they did. Directly on top of IP could work (with some IP protocol number allocated for BACnet) but would never cross a NAT router.